# eclipse cannot choose a running AVD

Tags: android, eclipse, android-virtual-device

When I want to run an  android project in `Eclipse`, it cannot choose a running `AVD` as below picture.Anyone knows what's wrong with it.Thanks a lot
[[image]

Comment: unplug ur device and usb from pc as well , connect it once again .try to "reset adb "and then run your app once again.

Comment: @Jig's It's an AVD (Android **Virtual** Device). Nothing to do with USB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens when `adb` starts before the `emulator`. so write in the command prompt

> adb kill-server
>    adb start-server

and Then

> adb device

or simply restart `eclipse`

Comment: If it worked then accept it bro..It will help others to find

Comment: Thank you. I restarted my PC, then this issue gone.